# How to change the gray-ish default toolbar/taskbar color of an app in node-webkit (NW.js) (I'm on a mac)?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I want to change the default toolbar color of my app. 
I would like to change it to this color: #16171a.
Here is a [link](https://popcorntime.io/images/graph-image.png) to an app built in NW.js with the toolbar color changed.

This is the package.json of my app

**package.json**

```
 {
      "name": "SampleApp",
      "main": "index.html",
      "window":{
        "toolbar": false,
        "width": 800,
        "height": 500
      }
    }
```

This is the index.html of my app
**index.html**

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <style>
      body{
        background-color: #16171a; 
      }
      h1{
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
      }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting that allows you to just change the colour. What you can do is use a frameless window and recreate the OS window interaction elements. All the info you should need is here: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Frameless-window